# How to keep nextjs index files inside their respective folders with next export

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-pages

I have a folder structure for `NextJs`

```
pages
├── blog
│   ├── index.jsx
│   ├── other.jsx
│   └── [slug].jsx
└── index.js
```

On `npx next build && npx next export` I get

```
├── 404.html
├── blog
│   ├── a1.html
│   ├── b2.html
│   ├── c3.html
│   └── other.html
├── blog.html
└── index.html
```

I want it to respect my content structure and generate the following tree instead

```
├── 404.html
├── blog
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── a1.html
│   ├── b2.html
│   ├── c3.html
│   └── other.html
└── index.html
```

Notice how `pages/blog/index.jsx` got exported as `./blog.html` instead of expected `./blog/index.html`

How do I prevent the default and generate in the expected format?

P.S: The entirety of the site is static and generated with help of `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`

Comment: there is no point in doing so. this is a production build used by servers and it is not for development. but in case you still want to take such action the only viable option is to check the NextConfig type to see if there is anything available otherwise you can do it by hand or using a bash script to move every x.html file to a folder with the name of x if the x folder already exists.

Comment: I've found something called https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash will check if it solves my use case and update

Comment: In case you really need it. you can create a script where it looks for *.html files and if the folder with the name of the file exists move it into the folder and rename it to index.html.

Comment: The `trailing-slash` setting didn't fix the issue as it now moves `other.html` to generate `other/index.html`, guess I'll look into scripting it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

this post is quite old but I just faced this issue today, in your `next.config.js` make sure to add `trailingSlash: true`, like:

```
module.exports = { trailingSlash: true}
```

that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

i did it and it works for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
async function clMagicFormat(){ 
    try{
        const outFilesList = await fs.promises.readdir(`${__dirname}/out`);
        outFilesList.forEach(async i => {
            if(i != 'index.html' && i != '_next' && i != 'assets' && i != 'favicon.svg'){
                await fs.promises.mkdir(`${__dirname}/out/${i.split('.html').join('')}`, { recursive: true });
                await fs.promises.rename(`${__dirname}/out/${i}`, `${__dirname}/out/${i.split('.html').join('')}/index.html`);
                await fs.promises.copyFile(`${__dirname}/out/favicon.svg`, `${__dirname}/out/${i.split('.html').join('')}/favicon.svg`);
                await fsExtra.copy(`${__dirname}/out/assets`, `${__dirname}/out/${i.split('.html').join('')}/assets`);
            }
        })
    }catch(err){
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
clMagicFormat();
```

Then in my Next.js script i set this:

```
"deploy": "npm run build && npm run export && node cl.magic.script.js
```